# Extract ngrams with R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am trying to extract `3-grams` from nirvana text by using the `ngramrr` package.

```
require(ngramrr)
require(tm)
require(magrittr)

nirvana <- c("hello hello hello how low", "hello hello hello how low",
             "hello hello hello how low", "hello hello hello",
             "with the lights out", "it's less dangerous", "here we are now",
             "entertain us", "i feel stupid", "and contagious", "here we are now", 
             "entertain us", "a mulatto", "an albino", "a mosquito", "my libido",
             "yeah", "hey yay")

ngramrr(nirvana[1], ngmax = 3)

Corpus(VectorSource(nirvana))
```

I get this result :

```
[1] "hello"      "hello"    "hello"              "how"  "low"       "hello hello"  "hello hello"      
[8] "hello how"  "how low"  "hello hello hello"  "hello hello how"  "hello how low"
```

I would like to know what can I do to construct `TermDocumentMatrix` where terms are the `tri-grams` list.

Thank you

Comment: I'd use `quanteda` and convert to `tm` format. `nirvana %>% tokens(ngrams = 1:3) %>% dfm %>% convert(to = "tm")`

Comment: @amatsuo_net thank you, can you help me with an R example please?

Comment: @Cath Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment above is almost complete but it is like this:

```
nirvana %>% tokens(ngrams = 1:3) %>% # generate tokens
  dfm %>% # generate dfm
  convert(to = "tm") %>% # convert to tm's document-term-matrix
  t # transpose it to term-document-matrix
```